# Is there any equipment/method that might help growing height?(20 yo male)

Tags: workout, bodybuilding, gym, exercise-equipment, growth

Sorry, this might be a dumb question, but I'm a 20 year-old male, only 170cm, I know I only have 1-2 years left for growing, and I've been trying everything to help me to grow height. Recently I just started to workout in gym, and I'm wondering is there any possible equipment/method that can help me to grow a little bit more?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, height is **largely** genetic.

However, nutrition is what impacts it from en environmental standpoint, and not exercise (it has a slight effect, assuming you are not a professional powerlifter, marathon runner or the like). So no, you cannot increase height by doing certain exercises. The notion that training basketball or volleyball makes you taller is wrong; professional basketball players are an artificially selected population, that is, if you are tall, you are more likely to play ball.

For example, doing heavy weight training in adolescence can negatively impact growth as nutrients are directed away from bone growth and toward muscle growth and maintenance. Chronic diseases affect growth similarly, by affecting nutrient supply.

Your height is determined as your parents' average +7cm for males, -7cm for females. There is some wiggle-room; in case your "genetic potential" is 170cm, then your resulting height will be a couple of cm's above or below, depending on external factors. In case you have a large supply of calories, and all necessary nutrients, then you can reach your maximal genetic potential.

Comment: Got a source for "heavy weight training in adolescence and negatively impact growth"?  From what I've read, the impact of increased natural testosterone and IGF-1 production while a teen is still growing affects bones as much as it does muscle.  However, once growth is done (somewhere around the early 20s) the hope of taking advantage of that is gone.

Comment: I too thought that lifting stunts growth, but while trying to find a reference I was surprised to find two papers stating the opposite. http://m.pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/107/6/1470.full http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3445252/

Comment: There is some logic to it; strenous exercise increases testosterone acutely, and from baseline following longer training, which subsequently increases growth velocity. However, thepapers do not state the opposite; strength training doesn't affect linear growth. The misconception, that I fell for, is that it decreases growth. As I see it, there is a possibility of stunted growth (due to injury of the epiphyseal plates), but no evidence for increased growth. So on a population level we can say that growth is decreased. On the individual level though, with proper technique, there is no difference

Answer (score 4):

While you won't be able to do much to impact the actual height of your body through exercise, to help make use of what you do have for height you can do exercises to strengthen your back and shoulders, leading to a more upright natural position which appears taller. Deadlifts are a great exercise to accomplish this; within a few months you should notice a difference in your posture while standing up. For cardio exercises, rowing is a great way to achieve similar results. The below image demonstrates how posture can add to perceived height.

[image: Comparison of postures]

As Darko mentioned, the most important thing for real height is to make sure you're eating a healthy diet, which will maximize the amount of growth which you have left.

Answer (score 2):

## No. Height is purely genetic.

There aren't any exercises you can do that will influence your height.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious Eat, Sleep, and be healthy advice…..

Weight Training my help you grow a little with the added production of hGH but the extra height would be negligible and it would be impossible to know.

Growth Hormone Treatment is the only real option to affect your height.  This is a big step as a specialized doctor needs to closely monitor the Hormone regiment.  Given that you are (assumption) an otherwise health 20 year old I doubt if you could find a doctor willing to help you.